# error: MyDocument.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object with a "html" prop set with a valid html string (in document.js)

Tags: reactjs

Now I'm making a mini project with react + node js + next server + express

and unexpected error is occuered

I don't know why an error occurs in _document.js.

If you know the reason, thank you for let me know

error:

```
Error: "MyDocument.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object with a "html" prop set with a valid html string
    at Object.renderToHTML (C:\node_bird_44\front\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:338:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
GET / 500 11240.415 ms - 21
[ event ] disposing inactive page(s): /, /_error
```

````
import React from 'react';
import Document , {Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static getInitialProps(context) {
        return { helmet: Helmet.renderStatic()};
    }

    render() {

        const { htmlAttributes, bodyAttributes, ...helmet } = this.props.helmet;
        const htmlAttrs = htmlAttributes.toComponent();
        const bodyAttrs = bodyAtributues.toComponent();

        return(
            <html {...htmlAttrs}>
                <head>
                    {Object.values(helmet).map(el => el.toComponent())}
                </head>
                <body {...bodyAttrs}>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </html> 
        );
    }
}


export default MyDocument;
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `html` prop which needs to be returned by getInitialProps. You can grab this from the Document initial props like so:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  return { ...initialProps, helmet: Helmet.renderStatic() }
}
```

Comment: The solution you gave me worked. It was a very difficult problem for me  
I'm glad to solve it. Thank you