# Error: "MyDocument.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object with a "html" prop set with a valid html string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

My project is in https://github.com/Talita1996/NLW4

1. I created a project with the command `yarn create next-app project_name`
2. I changed the extension of some files and added some code
3. I installed typescript with the command `yarn add typescript @types/react @types/react-dom @types/node -D`

On the first day everything worked fine, but today, when I call `yarn dev` I get the error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: MyDocument.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object with a "html" prop set with a valid html string (in document.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365958/error-mydocument-getinitialprops-should-resolve-to-an-object-with-a-html-p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your page/_document you need to extend Document class

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&family=Rajdhani:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>
        <body>
        <Main/>
        <NextScript/>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest the same thing with functional component for _document.js ? @hello-earth

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a function component, and fully typed with TypeScript.

```js
import NextDocument, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import type { DocumentContext, DocumentInitialProps } from 'next/document'

const Document = () => {
    return (
        <Html lang="en">
            <Head />
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}

Document.getInitialProps = async (ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> => {
    const initialProps = await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
}

export default Document
```

As pointed out in previous answers, you have to call `await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)` and spread the returned object in the `getInitialProps`'s return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have missed 'await' and then ad it :

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx){
  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
   return {...initialProps, locale: ctx?.locale || "fr"}
  }
```